# needing to color points according to gender when plotting height~weight in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a scatter plot for class. The final question ask for me to make a scatter plot showing if height and weight are significantly related, but the professor wants an illustrative scatter plot with the dots colored according to the gender of the person. The code I have is as follows. Also just as fair warning I am not particularly skilled in R, as this question probably makes obvious.

```
dt=read.csv("http://rfs.kvasaheim.com/stat4013/spencjw.csv")
attach(dt)
summary(dt)

###Section E 
table(height, weight, gender)
mod=lm(height~weight)
summary(mod)
confint(mod)

plot(height~weight, main="height vs weight", xlab="height",
 ylab="height", abline(lm(height~weight)))
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition to the general R introduction, recommended by @Stephan Kolassa, I would also recommend this nice introduction to R standard graphics by UCLA: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/introduction.htm (note that it doesn't cover `lattice` and `ggplot2`, covered elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your `gender` variable is coded, you can do :

- if `gender` is, for example 1 for men and 2 for women

  ```
  plot(height~weight, main="height vs weight", xlab="height",
   ylab="height", col=c("blue","pink")[gender])
  ```
- if `gender` is, for example "M" for men and "F" for women :

  `plot(height~weight, main="height vs weight", xlab="height", ylab="height",col=sapply(gender,switch,"M"="blue","F"="pink"))`

Answer (score 1):

If your `gender` variable is already a `factor`, then adding the `col=gender` parameter to your `plot()` command should already work. Otherwise, you may need to recode `gender` using `as.factor()`. Look at `?as.factor`.

Think about `pch=19`, too, I find this much more legible than the default circles.

I recommend reading *An Introduction to R*, which should be available as PDF under the Help menu of your R GUI.

And questions about programming specifically are a better fit for StackOverflow, in the R tag. I flagged this for closing & migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to do what You need

```
require(ggplot2)
dt=read.csv("http://rfs.kvasaheim.com/stat4013/spencjw.csv")
g <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=height, y=weight, colour=gender))
g <- g + geom_point()
g
```